# Why do churches have steeples?

Tags: church-building, architecture

What purpose do steeples serve? Are they put high up on church buildings as some sort of marketing tool so it can be seen from far away or is there some other reason(s)?

Comment: To keep in all of the sheeples.

Comment: Has anyone ever made the connection to church steeples to obleisks from anceint egypt, and others found around the world in Rome, and others like "the Washington Momument? http://aloha.net/~mikesch/wheel.htm

Comment: To @Josh: Did you know that the pagan obleisk before Vatican basilica is the exact same one before which St. Peter was crucified as a offering to a pagan god in Nero's circus? Also do you know that the cross on the top of it denotes the christian evangelisation of the pagan world? The eye sees what it wants to see.

Comment: One theory that might have some truth to it is that steeple design was taken from a pagan fertility (phallic) symbol and used to attract pagans into the memberships of early Christian churches. IMO, this makes sense since sex can be (as any Madison Ave. ad exec might also tell you) a powerful marketing tool.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Interesting question.  I managed to find an article, [*The History of Church Steeples*](http://www.religiousproductnews.com/articles/2007-February/Feature-Articles/The-History-of-Church-Steeples.htm), that actually addresses this.

One reason:  It was simply an architectural style that happens to inspire us to look heavenward.

> These early church architects designed grand cathedrals and churches
>   that had intricate, soaring steeples. The vertical lines of the
>   steeple helped to visually enhance the lines of the church, directing
>   the viewers' eyes vertically to the heavens. Obviously, this
>   verticality complements part of the mission of the church, to keep us
>   in a heavenly frame of mind, but from an architectural standpoint,
>   this vertical lift gives the architecture a more graceful and pleasing
>   look. The shorter the building, the more squat the appearance; the
>   taller the building, the more graceful it becomes. The early church
>   believed that the church could communicate the truth of the Bible in
>   pictures and symbols to those who were illiterate, such as using the
>   picture in the stained glass to tell stories, as well as the steeple,
>   which helped by pointing upwards devotedly to Heaven. Therefore, the
>   steeple has a dual role in that it helps the congregant in his or her
>   spiritual mindset, and the steeple also helps the architect with a
>   design feature that enhances the overall harmony of the architecture.

In short, there's no doctrinal significance, or symbolic other than the pointing to the Heavens. It's simply a beautiful style that, once done, was imitated throughout the ages until it became expected.

Comment: And let's not forget you need somewhere to put the bells.

Comment: In response to David Stratton's answer. On looking towards the heavens. Does anyone know anything pertaining to the physiological response to looking upwards. I hypothesis the muscles groups that are used and those that are relaxed when you look upward might have an effect on ones psyche that is favorable for the proselytizer. Pretty far-out idea, but wouldn't that be freaky?

Answer (score 5):

Because steeples have bells in them

[image: JEAN-FRANÇOIS MILLET - El Ángelus (Museo de Orsay, 1857-1859. Óleo sobre lienzo, 55.5 x 66 cm)]

See, they know they need to pray the Angelus because the bell is ringing.

Comment: I want to vote you up just for making me laugh, but this type of behavior should not be encouraged.  ;-) You're killin' me, Smalls!

Comment: Agreed, I was going to just write "Bells", but it said I needed 30 characters :)

Answer (score 4):

for the sound of bells to carry over the tops of buildings, the bells had to be higher than surrounding buildings.  Bells were used not only before church service, but also to notify people of emergencies, such as fires.  The buildings were regularly used as a town meeting place, as well, not like today where they are often locked except on Sunday mornings.

Answer (score 1):

The church has always been recognised as a patron of art as it has needed to use art for teaching and inspiring . Stained glass windows often contained depiction of scriptural teachings, and allegorical interpretation lent itself particularly  well to this form. Common folk found pictorial depiction easier to understand.

Thus the Samaritan would be depicted as Christ,  the wounded man as man under sin's oppression.

The other way art could be used was for inspiration . Cathedrals have been called prayers in stone, depicting the heavenward soaring of men's words.

People entering a place of worship were inspired to believe they were seeing and hearing men praising God through architecture and music. God was the recipient of this worship, and men's energies were used to create forms in a way that reflected this. Conscious effort was made in the soaring interiors and ethereal singing to convey the idea that God was present in all His Majesty.

Compare this with contemporary architecture  and music, where the end products have the consumer in view. Churches are patronised because they have comfortable seating, climate control and theatre acoustics, the better to hear words that comfort and beats that stir the feet to tap.

Comment: I agree with your modern analysis, but the historical purpose of stained glass (and lack of stained glass in the more tropical climates) in the pre-industrialized world was comfort as well as beauty.  Stained glass windows could keep churches warmer, but couldn't be opened for ventilation like wood paneling could.